# Error in uploading file on skydrive in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to upload some recorded audio files on sky drive after uploading some file i am getting an exception
"The application request limit has been reached".

how to handle this exception.
please suggest some solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After refering the link
  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.backgroundtransfer.backgroundtransferservice%28v=vs.105%29.aspx i found that background transfer service is capable of holding only 25 open requests at a time therefore it gives such exception.
To handle the above exception i used following code.

```
 List<BackgroundTransferRequest> list = BackgroundTransferService.Requests.ToList();
                    foreach (BackgroundTransferRequest item in list)
                    {
                        if (item.TransferStatus == TransferStatus.Completed)
                        {
                            BackgroundTransferService.Remove(item);
                        }
                    }
```

Apply this code when your request get completed. and if the request count reaches to 25 request stop sending more request until the previous are completed.